# How to create ViewPager (UIScrollView) like control in Godot?

Tags: godot, godot4

I have a page where I want to list out all the levels, say from 1-1000. Each level will be a button with number as text. It's not possible to list them all on a single page. I want to do 20 per page. Is there a way to add horizontal scroll that behaves the same as ViewPager (UIScrollView) where scrolling will be a full page in Godot? I'm guessing it has to be `ScrollContainer, but wasn't able to figure out how. Also, is there a way to populate all the buttons dynamically instead of manually adding 1000 buttons?

Comment: I found this tutorial https://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/4.x/ui/level_select/index.html to be very useful and ended up implemented the same.